# Length specified in network packet

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

> Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of
>   bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor
>   of the client library. [CLIENT: 218.76.28.18]

---

Hello mates, I got same error from different [CLIENT: IP addresses]. I have a cloud server and MSSQL Server 2014 intalled on it. But don't have any database at sql server. When i check logs i saw almost 500 error in last 7 days. All errors as above, only with different client IPs. Anyone know why i got this errors? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a botnet is probing your publicly accessible SQL Server.  Don't make your SQL Server publicly accessible by closing the relevant ports.

Comment: No DB does not restrict connection to server.

Comment: "Allow remote connections to this server" if i disable this option from server properties at Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, is it will be solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is connecting from a server with static IP, you can create a allowed policy for the IP. Rest all connection will be refused automatically.